# Get spesific data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get data from my data base firbase ("phone" child),
 you can watch photo:

https://b.top4top.net/p_936hbh5o1.png

am using this code to get data, but i have error (java.lang.NullPointerException).

```
 int i=0;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // instancie 
la BDD
    FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = 
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ; // recup le yser courent

    String id= currentFirebaseUser.getUid(); // recup id user actrulle
    DatabaseReference usersRef = 
mDatabase.child("Users").child(id).child("favoris");


    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i=0;
            //ArrayList Userlist = new ArrayList<favoris>();
            // Result will be holded Here
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String,Object>) 
 dataSnapshot.getValue();
                ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<Object> 
 (td.values());

                //favoris fav = (favoris) td.values();
                favoris fav = (favoris) objectArrayList.get(0);

                names[i]= fav.name;
                i++;

            }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE?

Comment: @DzAbdellatif At which line of code are you getting `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO class where you get the elements you want, in this case just phone, you can get also address and names, just add setters and getters here.

```
public class FavorisPojo {

    String phone;

    public FavorisPojo() {
    }


    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }



}
```

Then just iterate through all your nodes and get that:

```
 usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i=0;
            //ArrayList Userlist = new ArrayList<favoris>();
            // Result will be holded Here
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

              FavorisPojo favoris = dsp.getValue(FavorisPojo.class);
              String phone = favoris.getPhone();

            }
```

We use string to get the phone since it's loaded like that in your Firebase database, if you want to change it just change your variable name at your FavorisPojo class.

Also you will need one more level deep at your reference like so:

```
 DatabaseReference usersRef = 
mDatabase.child("Users").child(id).child("favoris").child(the_id_containing_after_favoris);
```